# Clone a generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I want to clone a generic object and preserve its type.

```
run.Append(style.Clone(BlackFont)); //run object accepts only RunProperties objects

public T Clone(T what) {
    if (what is RunProperties)
        return (T) what.Clone();
}
```

It doesn't work since T type does not have a Clone method, how can I overcome this without casting in the first statement.

```
run.Append((RunProperties) style.Clone(BlackFont)); //I do not want this
//not that this will work since you can't convert T to RunProperties
```

Thanks for any help.

---EDIT---

It seems that it would be better for my not to use generics in this case. I'll split up the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always constrain the method to only accept types that implement the ICloneable interface:

```
public T Clone(T what) where T : ICloneable
{
    if (what is RunProperties)
        return (T) what.Clone();
}
```

But since your method really only works with one type, you could change it slightly and use the `as` operator also:

```
public T Clone(T what)
{
    var castWhat = what as RunProperties;
    if(castWhat != null)
        return castWhat.Clone();
}
```

Comment: I'm planning to add more types, kept it simple as an example. Implementing now, hopefully works fine.

Comment: @skynorth - If that's the case, then go with the first option.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a function I wrote that clones a record of type T, using reflection.
This is a very simple implementation, I did not handle complex types etc.

```cs
public static T Clone<T>(T original)
{
    T newObject = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(original.GetType());

    foreach (var originalProp in original.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        originalProp.SetValue(newObject, originalProp.GetValue(original));
    }

    return newObject;
}
```

I hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to constrain the type of T to a type which implements [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

you're almost giving the answer yourself:

```
T type does not have a Clone method
```

Also, what is the point of a generic method if you only do something for one type?

The Clone method comes from the ICloneable interface, so you can implement your generic Clone method, making it work for all types that implement `ICloneable` like this:

```
public T Clone<T>(T what) where T: ICloneable
{
   return (T) what.Clone();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic constraint:

```
public T Clone<T>(T what) where T: ICloneable
{
    if (what is RunProperties)
        return (T)what.Clone();
    ...
}
```

or if the T generic parameter is defined on the containing class:

```
public class Foo<T> where T: ICloneable
{
    public T Clone(T what)
    {
        if (what is RunProperties)
            return (T)what.Clone();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest defining an interface ISelf<out T>, with a single read-only property called "Self", of type T (which, in any implementation, should return "this").  Them define ICloneable<out T> which inherits ISelf<T> and implements a method, Clone(), of type T.

Then, if you have a method which needs something which derives from type Foo and is cloneable, simply pass that method an ICloneable<Foo>.  To use the passed-in object as a "Foo", access its "Self" property.  I would suggest that classes with public clone methods should often be sealed, but extend unsealed types simply by adding a public "Clone" wrapper.  That will allow for the existence of derived types which do or do not allow cloning.

Consider the class family Foo, CloneableFoo, DerivedFoo, and CloneableDerivedFoo, and OtherDerivedFoo.

- Foo does not provide a public Clone method; it could be cloned without difficulty, and has a protected MakeClone method.

  CloneableFoo derives from Foo, and exposes a public Clone method which wraps MakeClone and implements ICloneable<CloneableFoo>.

  DerivedFoo is derived from Foo; like Foo, it but does not have a public Clone method, but offers a protected MakeClone method.

  CloneableDerivedFoo derives from DerivedFoo, and exposes a public Clone method which wraps MakeClone and implements ICloneable<CloneableDerivedFoo>.

  OtherDerivedFoo derives from DerivedFoo, but has class invariants which would be broken if cloned; it shadows MakeClone with a void function that is tagged obsolete-error.

Given those relationships, it would be useful for one method to accept any cloneable derivative of Foo, while another method will accept any derivative--cloneable or not--of DerivedFoo.  The first method should use a parameter of type ICloneable<Foo>, while the latter takes a parameter of type DerivedFoo.  Note that if DerivedFoo were derived from CloneableFoo rather than Foo, it would not be possible to have anything derive from DerivedFoo without promising a public Clone method.

Answer (score -1):

Use FastDeepcloner i developed
https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastDeepCloner/

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Clone Object, se FastDeepCloner for more information
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="items"></param>
    /// <param name="fieldType"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<T> Clone<T>(this List<T> items, FieldType fieldType = FieldType.PropertyInfo)
    {
        return DeepCloner.Clone(items, new FastDeepClonerSettings()
        {
            FieldType = fieldType,
            OnCreateInstance = new Extensions.CreateInstance(FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject)
        });
    }
```